# Conditionally adding a row after 3 elements: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to render several row containing three columns each. The columns have just a `Card`. The way I thought I could do this is to `map` through the elements and create a `row` when the `index` modulus is 0 and close that `row` when it's the third column of the row. I've tried with `if-else` statements and with ternary operators. But I keep getting syntax errors.

```
render(){
  var { isLoaded, items } = this.state;

  if(!isLoaded) {
    return (<div> Fetching items </div>);
  }
  else {
    var results = items.results;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className ="container">
        { result.map ((result, i) => {
          return(
            {i%3===0 ?
                <div className ="row mt-4">
                  <div key ={i} className="col-md-4">
                    <Card result={result}></Card> 
                  </div>
              :
                  <div key ={i} className="col-md-4">
                    <Card result={result}></Card> 
                  </div>);
              }
            {i%3===1 ?
                </div>
                :null}
              })}

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

With this piece of code I'm getting an error in this line

```
{i%3===0 ?
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: instead of using a ternary operator where you return null {i%3===1 ? </div> :null}, you can use the && instead like this {i%3===1 && <div></div> }

Comment: Empty element should be terminated like this `<div />` not `</div>`. I guess you must start using eslint. I've posted my answer.

Comment: @Filtenborg I also tried that, but still get the same error

Comment: @Avanthika Thank you. But unfortunately it's not just that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, you have a unclosed `<div>` tag which is invalid JSX, also `{` in return means an object not dynamic content.

Don't forget we write [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html), not html. Each tag needs to be closed properly, because it will get converted into `React.createElement(component/html tag, props, children)`.

To solve the problem, first prepare the array and after 3 items, just push the elements in row arrays, like this:

```
renderRows() {
  let results = items.results;
  let finalArr = [], columns = [];

  result.forEach ((result, i) => {

    // prepare the array
    columns.push(
      <div key ={i} className="col-md-4">
        <Card result={result}></Card> 
      </div>
    );

    // after three items add a new row 
    if((i+1) % 3 === 0) {
      finalArr.push(<div className ="row mt-4">{columns}</div>);
      columns = [];
    }
  });
  return finalArr;
}

render(){
  var { isLoaded, items } = this.state;

  if(!isLoaded) {
    return (<div> Fetching items </div>);
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className ="container">
          {this.renderRows()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What you say makes sense. I am getting a weird error though in the renderRows function. Unexpected token return

Comment: Sorry forgot to close the `)` for `forEach` callback method, try now.

Comment: Great stuff. That made it. Thank you

Comment: I just realized this will only work when the of items (results in the code) is a multiple of 3. If not, those items will not be shown at all since the row is not created

Comment: For example, if there are 10 elements, the first 9 will be shown as expected. But the last one won't

Comment: Ohh, wait will update the answer to handle that case

Comment: I just simply added
    if(columns.length !== 0){
      finalArr.push(<div key='last-row' className ="row mt-4">{columns}</div>);
      columns = [];
    }
that worked. Thanks!

Comment: @MayankShukla Could you edit the answer with the last fix you made in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing some closing brackets.

Try this,

```
<div className ="row mt-4">
{ result.map ((result, i) => {
    return(
         <React.Fragment>
      {(i%3===0) ?
           <div key ={i} className="col-md-4">
           <Card result={result}></Card> 
           </div>
           :
           <div key ={i} className="col-md-4">
           <Card result={result}></Card> 
           </div>
        }
          </React.Fragment>
      )
   })}
</div>
```

As per your code,

```
{ result.map ((result, i) => {
        return(
          {i%3===0 ?
              <div className ="row mt-4">
                <div key ={i} className="col-md-4">
                  <Card result={result}></Card> 
                </div>
            :
                <div key ={i} className="col-md-4">
                  <Card result={result}></Card> 
                </div>); //You have added `);` which is cause of error. this means you are returning this much part only.
```

Comment: Same as the first answer:
Why would this work? First, I still get the syntax error on the same line. Also, the opening '<div>' after the second ternary operator defeats the purpose of the closing </div> that wants to close the <div className ="row mt-4"> opened in the first ternary operator

Comment: After your edit, your code is the exact same as mine

Comment: @user3083022 NO. you have extra bracket <Card result={result}></Card> 
                </div>); this round bracket and semi colon not needed.

Comment: @user3083022 replace your code with my and check if you get any error. Also do post the error.

Comment: You are right. But it still does not work. Same error:

    Line 39:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

being line 39 the same first ternary operator

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can fix it:

```
render() {
    const { isLoaded, items } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return (<div> Fetching items </div>);
    }

    const results = items.results;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
          {results.map((result, i) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              {(i + 1) % 4 === 0 ?
                (<div className="row mt-4" key={`row-${i}`}>
                  <div key={i} className="col-md-4">
                    <Card result={result} />
                  </div>
                </div>) :
                (<div key={i} className="col-md-4">
                  <Card result={result} />
                </div>)}
              {i % 3 === 1 ? <div /> : null }
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I strongly suggest you to use ESLint or linter to find and fix these errors then and there. Take a look at: https://medium.com/@RossWhitehouse/setting-up-eslint-in-react-c20015ef35f7. Eslint will help you with better indentation, matching brackets, best practices and much more. Once you have set eslint, you can sort these out yourself.

**Edit:**

Grouping items into four and putting them under one row:

```js
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      isLoaded: true,
      items: {
        results: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoaded, items } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return (<div> Fetching items </div>);
    }

    const results = items.results;
    // Group them into sets of 4.
    const grouped = results.reduce((acc, post, ind) => {
       var index = parseInt(ind / 4);
       acc[index]= acc[index] || [];
       acc[index].push(<div key={`colmn-${index}`} className="col-md-4">{results[ind]}</div>);
       return acc;
     }, []);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
          {grouped.map((row, i) => {
          return <div className="row mt-4" key={`row-${i}`}>{row}</div>})}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("retrospect-app"));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="retrospect-app"></div>
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is creating a row for every element

Comment: Move the `<div className="row mt-4"` outside the loop avoid creation of new rows.

Comment: Then I will have one row with as many columns as are created. I want 1 row every 3 columns

Comment: I've edited my answer to match your requirement. Between, why do you need i % 3 === 1 check?

Comment: The way you suggest does not work: it will create a row with one column when (i + 1) % 4 === 0  resolves to true. And no rows for the rest.

Comment: @user3083022 are you trying to group the columns to fit into rows ? Group them as sets and then display it. I've attached a snippet to show how to do that, if that's what youre looking for. And your current requirement varies a lot from the question you posted. Please edit it too.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error, because you are not rendering a valid element each time - it is missing a closing  tag when "i%3===0" resolves to true.

```
 <div className ="row mt-4">
     <div key ={i} className="col-md-4">
         <Card result={result}></Card> 
      </div>
 </div> // <-- this one
```

Also, you could just render all the cards in that one container and set the style of the card accordingly to be the width of a third of the parent container.

```
 <div className="container">
   {result.map((result, i) => {
     return (
       <div key={i} className="col-md-4"> // add styles for width 30%
         <Card result={result} />
       </div>
     );
   })}
 </div>
```

And one other idea is that instead of feeding data like [1,2,3,4,5], you could reduce the array to buckets of other arrays like [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] and render those.

```
  <div className="container">
    {result.map((row, i) => (
      <div key={i} className="row mt-4">
        {row.map((col, i) => (
          <div key={i} className="col-md-4">
            <Card result={col} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
```

P.s. don't use the index for the element key. Use something unique, like the value of the card or an id.